# With EF CodeFirst, how can I specify the ID when creating an object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following objects:

```
public class User {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    IList<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job {
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime StartTime { get; set; }   // other fluff values here
    User User { get; set; }
}
```

I've already set up a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Job` (as it's appropriate), but I'd like to specify `Job.Id` when creating them.  I can guarantee, although perhaps Entity can't, that the Ids are unique since they're the PK of another table in a different system.

The following code illustrates what I want to work:

```
var user = db.Users.Create ();
var job = new Job();
job.Id = 42; // id from other service
user.Jobs.Add (job);

db.Users.Add (user);
db.Save ();
```

Some code is being omitted for brevity, and please let me know if I've omitted something that turns out to be necessary.  My `User` gets created and inserted, my `Job` gets created and inserted, but `Job.Id` is 1 instead of 42.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Job {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime StartTime { get; set; }   // other fluff values here
    User User { get; set; }
}
```

Should do what you need.

From [DataAnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

> Setting the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute on a column to Identity or
>   Computed forces the value for the column to be retrieved from the
>   server as an Identity or Computed value when you call SaveChanges.
>   Identity properties are read from the data source when the type is
>   first saved, but afterward, they are assumed to be unchanged. Computed
>   properties are read every time SaveChanges is called. **None indicates
>   that it is not a server generated property.** Identity is the default
>   value for integer key properties when working with Code First.

[DatabaseGenerated reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past, and this was the solution.